# Cast Varchar2 to date in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: sql, string, oracle, date, literals

I have a query in Oracle PL/SQL which gives an ordered list by the customer names, based on the % of bills, they paid with a delay. The query is the following

```
With date_check AS
    (Select *
        From tblBills
        Where Pay_Date Between CAST('2015-09-01' AS DATE) And CAST('2015-09-30' AS DATE)
    )
    Select ddo.CODE As "Customer Name",
      100.0 * ROUND(Cast(Count(fpp.ID) AS FLOAT)  / 
      ( Select Count(fpp2.ID)
        From date_check fpp2 
        Join tblMethods dppm2
         On fpp2.PAY_METHOD = dppm2.ID
        Where dppm2.IS_DELAYED = 'Y'), 2) As "% Delay"
    From date_check fpp
      Join tblMethods dppm On fpp.PAYMENT_METHOD_ID = dppm.ID
      Join tblCustomers ddo On fpp.CUSTOMER_ID = ddo.ID
    Where dppm.IS_DELAYED = 'Y'
    Group By ddo.CODE
    Order By Count(fpp.ID) Desc
```

When I run this query I receive the following exception:

> ORA-01861: literal does not match format string
>   01861. 00000 -  "literal does not match format string"
>   *Cause:    Literals in the input must be the same length as literals in
>              the format string (with the exception of leading whitespace).  If the
>              "FX" modifier has been toggled on, the literal must match exactly,
>              with no extra whitespace.
>   *Action:   Correct the format string to match the literal.

What is wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Either use date literals

```
Where Pay_Date Between date '2015-09-01' And date '2015-09-30'
```

or use the `to_date` function with an explicit format mask to convert strings to dates

```
Where Pay_Date Between to_date('2015-09-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD') And 
                       to_date('2015-09-30', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
```

A straight `cast` will use whatever the current session's `nls_date_format` is set to.  That is unlikely to be the same for every person over time so it is not something that you want to build code that relies upon.